# Aggregating rows and adding new variables

Tags: r, aggregate

I've a dataframe with thousands of rows, with two columns of my interest, ID and date. Some IDs are repeated, but not the dates. I want to have only one row for each ID, and then store the different dates into columns, like: UniqueID, date1, date2, and so on.

Does anyone know what is the best way to do that? I use R, is there any optimal way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
dates <- c("02/26/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92", "02/28/92", "02/01/92")
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,2), date = as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%y"))
```

dat looks as follows:

```
  id       date
1  1 1992-02-26
2  1 1992-02-27
3  2 1992-01-14
4  3 1992-02-28
5  2 1992-02-01
```

With the following trick

```
dat %>% 
  select(id, date) %>% #here you select the columns that you want to use
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(seq = paste0("date", row_number(id))) %>% 
  spread(seq, date)
```

become this:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: id [3]

     id      date1      date2
* <dbl>     <date>     <date>
1     1 1992-02-26 1992-02-27
2     2 1992-01-14 1992-02-01
3     3 1992-02-28       <NA>
```

Comment: Yes, I mean exactly this.

Thanks you!